# What is wrong in the below program to generation of permuation?

Tags: c#, linq

```
 var query = from p1 in Enumerable.Range(2,3)
                        from p2 in Enumerable.Range(4,5)                       
                        select new { p1 , p2};
```

The result seems to be wrong

```
{ p1 = 2, p2 = 4 }
{ p1 = 2, p2 = 5 }
{ p1 = 2, p2 = 6 }
{ p1 = 2, p2 = 7 }
{ p1 = 2, p2 = 8 }
{ p1 = 3, p2 = 4 }
{ p1 = 3, p2 = 5 }
{ p1 = 3, p2 = 6 }
{ p1 = 3, p2 = 7 }
{ p1 = 3, p2 = 8 }
{ p1 = 4, p2 = 4 }
{ p1 = 4, p2 = 5 }
{ p1 = 4, p2 = 6 }
{ p1 = 4, p2 = 7 }
{ p1 = 4, p2 = 8 }
```

Help needed

Comment: What's wrong with it? What result did you expect?

Comment: That result is exactly what I'd expect from that code. What did you expect, and why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to *guess* that you expected the results to be { 2, 4 }, { 2, 5 }, { 3, 4 }, { 3, 5 }. If that's the case, perhaps you missed that the second parameter to [`Enumerable.Range`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.range.aspx) isn't an upper bound - it's a length. In that case, you want:

```
var query = from p1 in Enumerable.Range(2, 2)
            from p2 in Enumerable.Range(4, 2)
            select new { p1 , p2};
```

Comment: Sir, I got relieve from a big doubt.. It was under the impression of Lower and upper bound as Enumerable.Range(lowerbound,upperbound) is same as for(i=lowerbound,i<upperbound;i++). But u cleared my doubt. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @priyanka.sarkar: If it had been an *exclusive* upper bound as you've shown, you'd only have received *one* value of course. But yes, basically the moral of the question should be that when something doesn't work as you initially expect it to, read the documentation :)